# RestHEART - How to prevent use of server-side Javascript in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am running RESTHeart for REST API access to a MongoDB instance, and I need to deny requests which would cause execution of any server-side Javascript in MongoDB. I cannot disable this feature outright per (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/#disable-server-side-execution-of-javascript) because I need this elsewhere, but I would like to prevent users with access to RESTHeart from using it. Is this possible via configuration changes? MongoDB user access controls? I'm not seeing an obvious option.